# Delphi: Unicode->AnsiString, language for non-unicode programs

Tags: delphi, unicode, non-unicode, ansistring

I have Delphi 2010.

XXX-component uses File_Path:AnsiString. A path can be written in XXX-language. If I set to use XXX-language for non-unicode programs in Windows settings then XXX-component recognize the path but if I set default Windows settings (English Windows-English for non-unicode programs) XXX-component can not recognize the path.

How to fix it?

Thank you!!!

Comment: The difference is the codepage. Delphi uses the system's default codepage (that is why it works if you set language to XXX) but that can be changed. Do you have control over the component's code?

Comment: No, I can not control. I changed all to String and it does not work.

Comment: Switching to string is your solution. You need to be more persistent with the port away from ANSI. What is XXX-component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to move away from ANSI strings and start using Unicode strings and the corresponding Unicode versions of the Windows API.  At the moment you are reliant on the computer locale and that's an enormous world of pain.

Moving from `AnsiString` to `string` takes a little effort but the benefits make the effort well worthwhile.

Embrace Unicode and forget all about the bad old days!

Comment: It wasnt THAT bad. Sometimes even didnt worth 2x memory increase.

Comment: @user it was that bad when you had to deal with non English languages. Actually, it was worse!

Comment: thats untrue. Everything is pretty smooth as long i do not want to itermix charsets within single data entity. An authentic words from the foreigner (from the place where major charset quantity was as high as five :-).